# Yii Dynamic Model Rule

Tags: php, yii

I would like to make a Yii Model rule dynamic, according to an attribute.

It's not giving error but also not working.
Am I doing something wrong? There any easier way to do it?

---

Model.php (Attributes: `NAME`, `TYPE`)

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // Name is only required when Type is equal 1.
        $this->type==1 ? array('name', 'required') : null,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to ( use `scenario`):

```
public function rules()
{
   return array(
      array('name', 'required','on'=>'typeTrue')
   );
}
```

And in controller

```
public function actionSome() {
  $model = new Model();
  if ( $model->type == 1 ) {
    $model->setScenario('typeTrue');
   }
}
```

Comment: Really thanks! I found it and already posted here the same answer. Il'l delete mine and accept yours. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and I would like to share.
For it need to use Yii rules `scenarios`.

Model.php:

```
 public function rules()
 {
     return array(
         array('name', 'required', 'on'=>'type1'),
     );
 }
```

Controller.php:

```
...
if ($model->type==1) {
     $model->scenario = 'type1';
}
....
```